# LiveCharts - Zero shows as exponential number on Y-axis

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, livecharts

I'm using LiveCharts on WPF to visualize log data. On the Y-axis, there are lists of doubles to be shown. 
The Y-axis' zero value (and in some cases, the values closest to it) are rendered as exponential numbers. In the meantime, the tooltips are showing the correct values (zeros).
I've tried to pass decimals instead, but with no result. I'm using 
LiveCharts 0.9.7 and .NET 4.5.
[0 on Y-axis is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8iw2.png)

I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the default CartesianChart.AxisY.LabelFormatter is not smart enough.

For now, you could easily add your own:

myChart.AxisY.LabelFormatter = value => value.ToString("N2");
Hope it helps!

Comment: In the end, I've set in the constructor:  YFormatter = val => val.ToString("N2"); and bound it in XAML: <lvc:Axis Title="Data" LabelFormatter="{Binding YFormatter}"></lvc:Axis> Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Last answer was a little bit vague for me.
I hope this help.

```
MyChart1_Disp.AxisY.Add(new LiveCharts.Wpf.Axis
        {
                Title = "Y Axis",
                LabelFormatter = value => value.ToString("N2"), // Format the labels with two decimal places
                MinValue = 0, // Set the minimum value of the Y-axis
                
                //Separator = new Separator { Step = 10 } // Set the separator to display labels at every 10 units
         });
```